# Writing to Excel file in Server using Node js from Client

Tags: javascript

I have an excel file in Server with a certain format. I have a client application that writes data to a database in Server. What I want to do is to take some of the label values from the front end and write it to the excel file every hour so that anyone with access can open the file and see which person has done what from the excel file without actually pulling data from the database. The front end is pure javascript. There are thousands of people using the application and I don't want to 
hinder the performance of the server. Is there a way to achieve this?